# how to implement logout beaviour in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an application which works when the user logs in. However, whenever there is a request to server and the reply contains session_expired, I need to clear the activity stack and show user just the login screen. This should be trivial however I am not able to find out a proper way to approach this without littering finish() inside every activity with conditional code. How can I just clear the activity stack and push just one activity? My application requires android 2.2 and up. I understand that it was introduced a new intent flag in honeycomb in order to just do that, but I need to support it for froyo and gingerbread also.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826757/android-how-to-logout-from-the-application however I know that approach and it is messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: although this does not solve my problem because of the way I structured my app but if I knew about it while creating app then it would definitely helped me, in future app this would work, however thename of flag is misleading.